Is "proactivity" a word?
Logically, proactivity should mean the quality of being proactive. However, I can't find it in dictionaries. Why is it not common? Do people use it at all? If not, which word do native speakers use instead?

Dictionary.com defines proactivity:

the act, characteristic, or habit of thinking and acting so as to prepare for, intervene in, or control expected events, especially negative or challenging ones; initiative:
Thanks again for your proactivity; you solved this problem before I even knew there was a problem!

This noun has lots of hits in Google Books.  Yes, it's a valid word.
Edit
Wikipedia has an entry too:

Proactivity or proactive behavior refers to self-initiated behavior that endeavours to solve a problem before it has occurred.

This word is not found in most other dictionaries, and I don't know what other criteria lexicographers have when it comes to deciding whether a word is to be included in their dictionaries other than this: Microsoft said that

Once a new word is added to a database, dictionary editors research how often a word is used. To add a new word to the dictionary, the word must be used frequently, have widespread use, and have meaningful use.

Elsewhere, the closest I found is a similar word proactiveness with the same meaning:

The state or condition of being proactive

So different lexicographers may possibly have slightly different criteria.

Yes, I did find that entry, but still,  do you have any idea why don't many other dictionaries include that word?

@An IELTS Learner, I've edited my answer.

@AnIELTSLearner Probably because the adjective is by far the most usual. But when you say dictionaries, it's hard to tell which one(s).

@Lambie, you’re right.  The adjective form is about 50 times more common.

Proactivity is an abstract word formed using a prefix and suffix of Latinate origin on an adjective also Latinate.  The suffix  -ity is applied to the adjective active making in an abstract noun; the prefix pro means  forward-looking,  indicating that it is the opposite of reactivity.  Latinate abstractions formed by analogy can  sound rather dorky. The understandable desire of speakers not to sound like dorks keeps the word from gaining traction.
